# google apps with IMAP and the from address is different from what is set up as the users' user name

Tags: email, google-workspace

I have a google apps account and on my user name is Jonathan Something but my 'from' email address is set to soemthing different than what my user name is. Where do I change this?

thx

**edit 1**

here is a screenshot of problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very small edit info on the right hand side. Can change info there

Answer (score 1):

The `From:` address in outgoing mail, in this circumstance, is set in your IMAP email client. Since you didn't specify which one you're using, it's impossible to give specific instructions, though all of them have settings to allow you to set your name as it should appear in outgoing mail.

Comment: thx Michael, I agree with your observation. I am using the webmail client and have included a screenshot of the account setting. thx

Comment: Oh, so you're using Gmail. What's the thing about IMAP for, then?

Comment: So, I can't find where I can set the From email in IMAP - it looks like this is an email level setting and NOT an admin level setting. Thx

Comment: Again, what email client are you using?

Comment: just web interface.

Comment: Then why do you keep mentioning IMAP?

Comment: Looks as if the google app settings go a different path once you set it as an IMAP account. Sorry for any confusion. If I'm incorrect - I really just want to change the sent from for the web interface. Any help is appreciated. I get the screenshot by going to Settings -> Accounts thx